# How to implement CSS on asp.net MenuControl's ToolTip

Tags: asp.net, tooltip

in my website I have a menucontrol, I want to implement CSS on Tooltip of MenuItem.
If any one has any Idea.

Answer (score 0):

Download Firebug [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/)

Use that to inspect the tooltips to work out how to access them. Then style away! :0)